# how to turn a whole <tr> into a link

Tags: html, css

I have the following code:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td><a href="#">some text</a></td>
    <td>some more text</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I am trying to turn the whole row of this table into a hyperlink, however I do not want to use the JavaScript mouse event as i am restricted from using JavaScript. I have tried using CSS but only found ways to make an individual  into a hyperlink by going: `a href style="display block;"` , does anyone know a css way to turn the whole row into a hyperlink?

Comment: Maybe you're restricted from using Java, but what about JavaScript?

Answer (score 9):

No, you can't turn an element/field into a clickable link-following element/field with CSS only. You will need to either include an ANCHOR within each header/cell within the TR (and set the ANCHOR to `display: block` so the entire cell is clickable), or use Javascript to make your TR or TR TH/TD's clickable/followable to the browser.

Example (of the ANCHOR approach):

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/V9kj5/1/

```
tr a {
    display: block;
}
tr td {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    width: 200px;
}

<table>
<tr>
    <td><a href="http://www.google.com" target="_google">some text</a></td>
    <td>some more text</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><a href="http://www.google.com" target="_google">some text</a></td>
    <td><a href="http://www.google.com" target="_google">some more text</a></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This does not stretch the link to the full cell height, see my fork of your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/timbuethe/BsKz8/

Comment: I don't see any difference between yours and mine, so I assume you didn't save after making your changes?

Answer (score 3):

While very similar to @Jared Farish's response, this setup should make the anchor take up the whole cell:

```
td a {

    display: inline-block;
    height:100%;
    width:100%

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NAfC5/2/

Answer (score 2):

CSS specifies the *presentation* of a page, while hyperlinks specify the *functionality*. No, you cannot use CSS to make an entire row act link an anchor. You will need to use JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

My general reaction is to say that you can't, but you can make the first link very wide and absolutely position it so that its hit area covers the second text cell.  However, the second text cell won't have other link styling.  You'll also need to specify a width for the first cell so it doesn't collapse due to the absolutely positioned link within.

[**See example →**](http://jsfiddle.net/UkW2p/)

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td width="100"><a href="#">some text</a></td>
        <td>some more text</td>
    </tr>
</table>

tr {
    position:relative;
}

tr a {
    display:block;
    width:98%;
    position:absolute; top:10px; left:10px; z-index:10;
}
```

Comment: @mVChr - You would need to take into account multiple lines: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/UkW2p/1/ Maybe `position: relative`?

Comment: I agree, but I wanted to propose a solution if he was unable or had limited access to modifying the actual HTML.

Comment: @Jared Farrish - good point, I thought the position:relative on the tr would cover that

Comment: @mVChr - Not in FF4 - I have one link in the top, left, and two cells to the right. This isn't really what a table would look like, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do, modulo HTML parser weirdness is make an `<a href>` into a table row by setting it to `display: table-row`.  But then you'll have to deal with HTML parsers fixing up `<td>` inside `<a>` for you.  If your page is XHTML, this will work really easily, though.