# How to make a table tr into a link?

Tags: javascript, html, css, hyperlink, tablerow

Here is my current solution:

```
<tr onclick="window.location = '/info/{{ match.login.id }}/'">
    <td>{% if match.image %}<img src="{{ match.image|crop:'64x64' }}" alt="Match Avatar" />{% endif %}</td>
    <td>{{ match.team_name }}</td>
    <td>{{ model|distance_to:match }} {{ model.display_distance }}</td>
    <td>{% for expertise in match.expertise_list %}
            <span{% if expertise in model.expertise_list %} class="match"{% endif %}>{{ expertise }}</span><br />
    {% endfor %}</td>
    <td>{% if model|active_connection_with:match %}{{ model|status_with:match }}{% else %}<a href="javascript:connect({{ match.login.id }})" class="button">Connect</a>{% endif %}</td>
```

But the thing that is wrong with this is that I want to be able to right click and copy link etc. How can i accomplish this?

Comment: Possible Duplicate: [how to turn a whole `<tr>` into a link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5784781/how-to-turn-a-whole-tr-into-a-link)

Comment: I think the purpose is different - it's not the "how", it's the right-click, which is not addressed in the other answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's invalid markup (and doesn't work on browsers) when you have HTML elements between table elements (tr, td, th).

If your table cells are too complicated to mark up as a link, what you can do is have an invisible `<a>` element that covers each `<td>` that you want to link:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="http://google.com" class="overlay"></a>
            Google
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="http://yahoo.com" class="overlay"></a>
            Yahoo
        </td>
    </tr>

</table>

td {
    position: relative;
}

.overlay {
    background-color: transparent;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/waitinforatrain/puTbj/1/

The only downside is that users can't select the text under it.

Answer (score 2):

Right-click to copy a link only works on the `A` tag. You'd have to write your own right-click hander.

Comment: How would you do that?